# Apply fotorama in Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, fotorama-slider

How to use fotorama in product image as like in magento2.

I want to add all functionality like previous/next click , image hove zoom etc. in magento1.9 as like magento 2.

How to apply fotorama in product image?

Anyone know about this? Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add css and js file of fotorama in layout of xml file :

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script>
```

Then add images like this :

```
<div class="fotorama">
  <img src="imageurl">
  <img src="imageurl">
</div>
```

If you want to dynamically add images in slider, then you need to add images between this div `<div class="fotorama"></div>`